# Definite integral application

Tags: definite-integrals

So, the task is to calculate the area of a shape in xOy plane bounded by functions: $y = x\sqrt{4x-x^2}$ and $y = \sqrt{4x-x^2}$
Could you please explain how I can solve this? How can I find the intersection points of these functions and how do I know which function has a bigger y value for the range of x values.

Comment: First step: Graph both functions in one xy plane with a graphing utility

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The domain of both functions is given by $$4x-x^2=x(4-x)\ge0,$$i.e.$$0\le x\le4.$$

Then the intersections are such that
$$x\sqrt{x(4-x)}=\sqrt{x(4-x)}.$$

This occurs at $x=1$ and the endpoints of the domain, $x=0,x=4$.

Obviously, $LHS\ge RHS$ when $x\ge 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

Blue  $\rightarrow y=\sqrt{4x-x^2}$

Purple $\rightarrow y=x\sqrt{4x-x^2}$

[image: Graph]